# Threading attribute table in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop

Is there a way to put ArcMap's attribute table on a different thread or processor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No ArcMap is a multithreaded program but can only utilize a single processor.

Comment: jeez that sucks

Comment: you can use multiprocessing with GP tools.                                                       https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/09/26/distributed-processing-with-arcgis-part-1/